# Iterating over google multimap passed as a parameter

Tags: java, google-maps

I have the following multimap:

```
private ListMultimap<String, int[]> terrainMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    {
        terrainMap.put("Terrain.Ground", new int[] {0,100,300,0});
        terrainMap.put("Terrain.Ground", new int[] {300,200,400,0});
        terrainMap.put("Terrain.Ground", new int[] {400,250,800,0});
        terrainMap.put("Terrain.Ground", new int[] {800,500,810,0});
        terrainMap.put("Terrain.Ground", new int[] {100,200,150,150});
        terrainMap.put("Terrain.Ground", new int[] {500,400,600,350});
    };
```

When I iterate through this in the same class, everything works as expected:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, int[]> entry : terrainMap.entries())
{

}
```

However, when I pass the map as a parameter of some other class method, I get an error `incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to entry<String, int[]>`

```
otherClassMethod(terrainMap);
```

And the method looks like this:

```
public void otherClassMethod(ListMultimap terrainMap)
{

}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What is the content of `otherClassMethod`? Where do you get this error?

Comment: The content doesn't matter, even empty function with only that empty for loop shows an error. By the way, this code has nothing to do with google maps :D

Comment: And I'm getting this error in the for line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use generics in the method signature rather than a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) so that the type can be determined from the collection

```
public void otherClassMethod(ListMultimap<String, int[]> terrainMap)
```

Comment: You shouldn't get an error if you passed something of type `List<T>` into something that is expecting `List`. You could get an unchecked warning though. The error is also talking about `entry<String, int[]>`, so I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: Quite strange, because that should never be a compilation error. Is the loop inside that method? That is why. You made it seem like the error was on the calling line.

Comment: @Reimeus OP made it seem like the error was on the line where he was calling the method. It would never throw an error there. But it would if the loop was moved inside that method. I just misread the question.

Comment: @VivinPaliath you didnt misread it, the key detail about the loop being inside the method was missing, seemed like the error was being created by the method call :)